# Customize the file generated by `rails new`

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've developed some nuances and a style, and my databases are configured in a certain way that means I have to tweak the YAML every time I start a new project.

Can I customize the `rails new` command, or should I just create a custom rake task to alter the files, and copy + paste the rake task into each new project to run it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Rails Templates to achieve your goal. There is a [RailsCast episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/148-app-templates-in-rails-2-3) that can help you.